# Python: What library to use to generate an animation from scratch

Tags: python-2.7, animation, libraries

I'm coding in Python 2.7, using a Windows 8 machine, and theI'd like to generate an animation which starts as a colored grid, and then in any next still frame of the animation, updates the colors of the grid based on current grid colors. For instance, I might have a given grid block turn white if it were adjacent to a white block in the previous still frame.

So I need to have a way of drawing a picture from scratch (I.e. not depend on loading and then manipulating an image already stored on my computer) and then generating an animation based on this, using some logical instructions that condition on the state of the image at any time.

I'm not sure what would be the best way to do this in outline. Which library (ies) would handle this best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Tkinter for that. And its in the standard python modules.

[Tkinter documentation](http://effbot.org/)